# HTML INPUT RADIO vaciar el valor de un radio button con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, select, radiobutton

Buen día estoy fucionando un input SELECT el cual segun el elemento desplega un grupo diferente de Radio Button pero necesito que los radiobutton no este seleccionados cuando muestre un nuevo grupo esten todos los radio esten deseleccionados y quiero hacerlo con JavaScript

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar tú código y los resultados que obtienes?

Comment: Te invito a que veas la sección de [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque cuando inicias la página no hay ninguno seleccionado, una vez que has seleccionado uno has de deseleccionarlos manualmente.
Aquí va un ejemplo:

HTML

```
<input id="rad1" type="radio" name="grpRadio">
<input id="rad2" type="radio" name="grpRadio">
<input id="rad3" type="radio" name="grpRadio">
<input id="btnReset" type="button" value="Reset">
```

JS

```
var btnReset = document.getElementById("btnReset");
if (btnReset) {
    btnReset.onclick = function () {
        resetRadioButtons("grpRadio");
    }
}
else {
    alert("btnReset not found");
}

function resetRadioButtons(groupName) {
    var arRadioBtn = document.getElementsByName(groupName);

    for (var ii = 0; ii < arRadioBtn.length; ii++) {
        var radButton = arRadioBtn[ii];
        radButton.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.